# Flask: request.method =='POST' skips return statement

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I have a strange problem with my app.

What I am doing is:
I generate a csv file in JS(client side) and then send it to flask where I then filter the file using python script and then return it back to the client.

Everything works great except the last part. When it comes to **return render_template** it just skips that part. Which is strange since it goes inside of the **if request.method == 'POST'**. I printed the values inside of the **if request.method=='POST'** and I can see the values on the server side.

Flask routes.py :

```
@app.route('/update_file', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def update_file():
    '''Opens the filtered_file page but with updated file'''
    clicked = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        clicked = io.StringIO(request.form['data'])
        file_to_filter = pd.read_csv(clicked, sep=',', engine='python', encoding='utf_8_sig')
        table1 = update_csv(file_to_filter)
        print(table1)
        table2 = table1.to_html(classes='my_class" id = "my_id')
        return render_template('3_filtered_file.html', data=table2)
```

This is how I show it on my html template :

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
    {{data | safe}}
</div>
```

I already did similar with the client uploaded file and it works great but this one has an error that I can't seem to find :/

**EDIT:**
This the JS where I send the ajax rquest:

```
//On Update click renders table to csv, activates the be_filter and reopens it in the filtered_file.html
var isClicked;
jQuery("#update").on('click', function(){
    var response = confirm('Are you sure you want to UPDATE rows ?');
    if(response == true){                    
        isClicked = $('#my_id').table2csv();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"{{url_for('update_file')}}",
            data: {'data': isClicked}
        });
         //window.location.href='/update_file';
    }else{
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: this is strange. I thought this was also fixed. What does your table1.to_html does? should it be table1.to_html(classes="my_class", id = "my_id")?

Comment: Where is your 3_filtered_file.html? is it inside templates folder?

Comment: yes it is in the templates folder

Comment: What exactly do you see in the browser when you press Ctrl+U after the POST request / form submission? Is anything rendered at all? Can you see `<div class="table-responsive">` in the source? Did you check the browser console for error messages?

Comment: to_html is just a function that takes csv file and renders it as a html table so you can open it in html . I already did this for the uploaded file and it worked

Comment: If I just execute after POST it returns this : `TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.` but if I add an **else** statements it accepts its return, but strange part is that is still goes first in the **if request.method..** and then skips its return statement and goes to else

Comment: Can you show the full view function? And I guess you're making the request via AJAX? Can you show the JS code? Is it possible you're running both a POST and a GET request because the form is submitted via AJAX *and* regularly? And the GET request causes the error because the view function doesn't return anything?

Comment: I looked at your prev question js. As you are using ajax for posting data. Your render_template returns the html to render but you are not using it anywhere. Check the console you will have rendered html logged there.

Comment: @ChrisG I just added the ajax call which I use to send the csv file from JS to flask

Comment: Right, as far as I can tell the request does go through and the file is updated on the server, but you don't see anything happen on the client. The problem seems to be that you're discarding the reply sent by flask. Add `success: function (reply) { console.log(reply); }` to your `$.ajax` options. You should also inspect the XHR in the browser's console; you can check exactly what the reply is. To be clear: `$.ajax` sends a request but it does not make the browser navigate to the result as submitting a form would.

Comment: @ChrisG I added the `success:function(reply){}` it show the current html from where I am sending the file

Comment: It should show the result of `render_template('3_filtered_file.html', data=table2)`, which it does I guess. Which means everything works as coded. The question is: what do you actually want to happen instead? Again, the CSV file on the server should update. And if you aren't getting any errors, everything works fine.

Comment: @ChrisG yes it returns the rendered template but only in the console.log .. I want to reopen my csv file in this template as a table but it doesn't work. So it still skips the return render_template. How can I make it work, if everything seems like it should work ?

Comment: No, it doesn't skip the render_template call. I'm writing an answer, give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you're using AJAX when you should be submitting a form instead. AJAX is primarily about communicating with the server *in the background*, but you're trying to use it as a tool for submitting POST form data programmatically. Using AJAX will send a request to the server just like clicking a link or submitting a form would, but the browser *does not navigate to the result*. This is why you concluded that flask skips the `render_template` call, but the template does indeed get rendered. It's just that with an AJAX call, the reply only ends up in the AJAX success callback, not in the browser's main window.

In the case of an AJAX request like this, there's no need to send back HTML. You could for instance simply return `"update successful"`.

You can fix your existing code by redirecting to the result page manually from the client:

```
// in your $.ajax() options:
success: function(reply) {
  if (reply == "update successful") location = "/table"; // URL of table view
  else alert("server reports error");
}
```

This will redirect on the client after the AJAX call has successfully updated the CSV file on the server.

However you can simply submit an actual form instead:

```html
<form id="tableDataForm" method="post" action="{{url_for('update_file')}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="data" id="tableData">
</form>
```

```js
$("#update").on('click', function(){
    $('#tableData').val($('#my_id').table2csv()); // insert data into hidden <input>
    $('#tableDataForm').submit();  // send POST request
});
```

This is all you need. Now the browser will once again display the reply sent back by flask.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I don't want to just save the csv file on server. I want to send it to server where it goes through a filter( so to speak) - python script and then I send it back to client side and represent it as a html table. When I do as you wrote with `success` it just returns the "3_filtered_file" html without the data: my filtered file

Comment: Ok, so is `3_filtered_file.html` a full HTML file? In that case use the `<form>` solution and it will appear in the browser, `data` inserted and all. Do not use AJAX unless you know how it works.

Comment: yes it is full HTML file. I tried your solution with `<form>` it finally returns HTML with the data, but also returns the `GET 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`

Comment: Not sure how to help you with this, sounds like a flask issue unrelated to this question.

Comment: probably, :/ will try to search for the solution, but thank you for the time you invested in helping me. I used both of the ways you posted, 1. with forms since I had to return the data again and 2. with ajax since I just send to server input.